# how to install ui-grid angular-ui

Tags: gruntjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to use angular ui-grid 3.0
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial

The question is how to install it? As explained, bower install ui-grid is not working.

I downloaded the specific files from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release

- How and where to add the link of these files?
- I am using grunt with yeoman. Should it be in Gruntfile.js? Then how?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Bower as your client-side package manager, you can install `ui-grid` with the following command:

```
bower install angular-ui-grid
```

(According to this repository https://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a yeoman generator, you must go into the directory where your bower.json and gruntfile.js (assuming your are using grunt) reside in; then run the command

```
bower install angular-ui-grid --save
```

If you run this, the dependency will be loaded will be listed in the bower.json and install automatically the script and style tags automatically.

Happy coding!